# passing a simple_fields_for object in a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, simple-form-for

So i have this js.erb file which is called when i make an ajax call.

In this file, i have this line of code

re_render.js.erb

```
 $('#id_employer').empty()
 $('#id_employer').append("<%=j render 'self_evaluations/self_evaluation_partials/step_2', :kyc => @kyc %>");
```

abc.html.erb

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :kyc_answer do |kyc| %>
  <div id="id_employer">
    <%= render 'self_evaluations/self_evaluation_partials/step_2'%>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

in my partial, i have this

```
<div class="flex_center flex_column">
   <%= kyc.collection_radio_buttons(:employer_type, employer_list, :first, :last,item_wrapper_tag: false) do |b|
     b.label(class: 'employer_type_radio') { b.radio_button + b.label{b.text}}
   end %>
</div>
```

Basically, i make an ajax call that renders `re_render.js.erb` which is basically just removing the previous contents of `$('#id_employer')` and re_rendering the partial again.

My question mainly was is it possible to somehow maybe in the controller, created a simple_form object which i can then pass as a local object back to the partial which wont make me change my current partial code.

I get an error 
`NoMethodError - undefined method`collection_radio_buttons' for #:`

I know this is because of the nested_attributes which has been passed before to the form for kyc_answer. How do i pass the simple_fields_for object again in my partial?

Thanks

Comment: What's `@kyc` and where / how is it defined?

Comment: @SRack it is just an object.

Comment: What's the scope of such object, can you add the whole code?

Comment: What Sebastian said. I asked as it looks like it's coming through as nil, a collection or similar. (The full error would also help, rather than cutting it off half way through.)

Comment: thanks guys for the input. i have updated the question to be  more clear.